# Wrong MYSQL (date) output

Tags: mysql

i have a database that contains over 2000 records and the date is wrongly formatted (mm/dd/yyy). I need to change this with mysql into dd/mm/yyy.

i have this code: 
UPDATE wp_team_workshop_availbility SET available_date = DATE_FORMAT('available_date', '%d-%c-%y')

but all i creates is an empty field.

Comment: what kind of data type you have for the `available_date` field?

Comment: Do you store data as varchar?

Comment: the type is varchar(50)

Comment: It appears that is a varchar.  It also looks like you have the `available_date` column single-quoted as a string inside `DATE_FORMAT()`. Should be unquoted, as you have it in `SET`.

Comment: it returns '0000-00-00' when i use this code:
UPDATE wp_team_workshop_availbility SET available_date = DATE_FORMAT(available_date, '%d-%c-%y')

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing it as a date (datatype), it is just a date - there is no format. However, you also don't want `available_date` as a quoted string, which is trying to convert the string "available_date" into a date.

My guess is you have the date stored as a string (you really shouldn't). However, what you will want is something more like:

```
UPDATE wp_team_workshop_availbility
   SET available_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(available_date,'%c/%d/%Y'), '%d-%c-%y');
```

i.e. you need to convert the string to a date and then convert it back to a string.

But really, you should take advantage of this opportunity to change your storage so you are using the right datatype.

Comment: i get an error with your code: Table 'wordpress_olympicmoves.wp_team_workshop_availability' doesn't exist

Comment: @MaartenGeuns - sorry, I had not noticed you misspelled "availability" in your table name. I'll change my answer to misspell it correctly, if that makes sense.